# Error: Not found: Dataset my-project-name:domain_public was not found in location US

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to make a query for a dataset provided by a public project. I created my own project and added their dataset to my project. There is a table named: `domain_public`. When I make query to this table I get this error:

```
 Query Failed
Error: Not found: Dataset my-project-name:domain_public was not found in location US
Job ID: my-project-name:US.bquijob_xxxx
```

I am from non-US country. What is the issue and how to fix it please?

**EDIT 1:**
I change the processing location to `asia-northeast1` (I am based in Singapore) but the same error:

```
Error: Not found: Dataset censys-my-projectname:domain_public was not found in location asia-northeast1
```

Here is a view of my project and the public project `censys-io`:

[image]

Please advise.

**EDIT 2:**
The query I used to type is based on censys [tutorial](https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/bigquery-introduction) is:

```
#standardsql
SELECT domain, alexa_rank
FROM domain_public.current
WHERE p443.https.tls.cipher_suite = 'some_cipher_suite_goes_here';
```

When I changed the `FROM` clause to:

```
FROM `censys-io.domain_public.current`
```

And the last line to:

```
WHERE p443.https.tls.cipher_suite.name = 'some_cipher_suite_goes_here';
```

It worked. Shall I understand that I should always include the `projectname.dataset.table` (if I'm using the correct terms) and point the typo the Censys? Or is this special case to this project for some reason?

Comment: what exactly do yo mean by "added their dataset to my project"?

Comment: I click on the right arrow next to my project -> switch to project -> display project -> then enter the public project ID. After that I see their datasets and tables in the navigation panel.

Comment: Did you follow these guidelines? Standard SQL only, etc - https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/bigquery-introduction

Comment: @J.L Valtueña yes I did.

Comment: I tried to add the dataset following this (https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/adding-censys-datasets-to-bigquery) and is not working. Maybe the dataset was deleted or changed the ID?

Comment: The dataset is added with me correctly. The first test query [here](https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/adding-censys-datasets-to-bigquery) works fine with me. But the second query `#standardsql
SELECT domain, alexa_rank
FROM domain_public.20171006
WHERE p443.https.tls.cipher_suite = 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA';` (with the exception that I added LIMIT 2 before the semicolon), which is from the same table I want, doe produce the error in this post.

Comment: This query works, but not the one above. `#standardsql
SELECT fingerprint_sha256, parsed.names, metadata.updated_at
FROM `censys-io.certificates_public.certificates`,
UNNEST(parsed.names) AS names
WHERE names = 'censys.io`

Comment: The project owners just added my account to give me access and they are still actively running the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem turned out to be due to wrong table name in the `FROM` clause.
The right `FROM` clause should be:

```
FROM `censys-io.domain_public.current`
```

While I was typing:

```
FROM domain_public.current
```

So the project name is required in the `FROM` and `` are required because of `-` in the project name.

Answer (score 22):

BigQuery can't find your data

### How to fix it

Make sure your `FROM` location contains 3 parts

1. A project (e.g. `bigquery-public-data`)
2. A database (e.g. `hacker_news`)
3. A table (e.g. `stories`)

Like so

```
`bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`
```

*note the backticks

### Examples

**Wrong**

```
SELECT *
FROM `stories`
```

**Wrong**

```
SELECT *
FROM `hacker_news.stories`
```

**Correct**

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem, if you click on QUERY TABLE the UI automatically fills out the query as you posted under "Correct", but it still fails with not found in US

Comment: @karlpy I haven't used in a little while so I'm a little rusty. Can you double check which region you're using and make sure it matches the region the data is stored in? that's the only other thing I can think of

Answer (score 12):

In Web UI - click <kbd>Show Options</kbd> button and than select your location for "Processing Location"!

> Specify the location in which the query will execute. Queries that run in a specific location may only reference data in that location. For data in US/EU, you may choose Unspecified to run the query in the location where the data resides. For data in other locations, you must specify the query location explicitly.

---

> Update

As it stated above  - `Queries that run in a specific location may only reference data in that location`

Assuming that `censys-io.domain_public` dataset has its data in US - you need to specify US for Processing Location

Comment: I went to the `show options`. I found US, EU, asia-northeast1 and unspecified. I am based in asia at the moment so I picked the asia-northeast. But when I run the query I get: `Query Failed
Error: Not found: Dataset censys-io:domain_public was not found in location asia-northeast1
Job ID:my-projectname:asia-northeast1.bquijob_4a55c23d_xxx

Comment: If the dataset is not actually stored in asia-northeast-1, then you can't set that as the processing location and expect it to work. Click on the dataset in the UI and I suspect that you will see a different location.

Comment: I also get this error when the table doesn't exist (if, for example, i search for table `asdfghjkl` in the dataset, so don't be too thrown off by the error about the processing location.

Comment: I control + f searched 'show options' and cannot find any, also checked the page source. Has this changed? (it's a very busy page)

Comment: @user5783745 - original answer is for so called Classic UI. You most likely looking into new UI - BigQuery Console - in this New UI you should click on More ... button and then Query Settings. In opened panel you will be able to find location related settings

Answer (score 2):

In my case there was a very strange thing - it was the same error but the solution was to add a space after a table name:

```
`vld3gda.warehouse_orders.orders` -- error
`vld3gda.warehouse_orders.orders ` -- no error
```

Answer (score 2):

create the dataset as a "multi-region" and as US (Multiple regions in the United States) ,this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your FROM location contains 3 parts as @stevec mentioned

- A project (e.g. bigquery-public-data)
- A database (e.g. hacker_news)
- A table (e.g. stories)

But in my case, I was using the LegacySql within the Google script editor, so in that case you need to state that to `false`, for example:

```
var projectId = 'xxxxxxx';
    
var request = {
  query: 'select * from project.database.table',
  useLegacySql: false
};
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
```

Answer (score 1):

check exact case [upper or lower] and spelling of table or view name.
copy it from table definition and your problem will be solved.

i was using FPL009_Year_Categorization instead of FPL009_Year_categorization

using c as C and getting the error "not found in location asia-south1"

I copied with exact case and problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

On your Big Query console, go to the Data Explorer on the left pane, click the small three dots, then select query option from the list. This step confirms you choose the correct project and dataset. Then you can edit the query on the query pane on the right.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

may be dataset name changed in create dataset option. it should be US or default location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtL2t.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).