# Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [4:7]

Tags: google-bigquery

I added a public database that uses standard sql. It appears as follows:
[image]

I add `#standardsql` in addition I changed that from the settings. The query looks like:

```
#standardsql
SELECT field1,field2
FROM `censys-io.domain_public.current`
WHERE filed3 = "some_string_here";
```

I get this error:

```
 Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [4:7]
```

Can you please tell me the reason and how to fix the issue

Comment: It is confusing. Can you elaborate. The project owner has post [here](https://support.censys.io/google-bigquery/bigquery-introduction). I am running exactly the second query:`#standardsql
SELECT domain, alexa_rank
FROM domain_public.20171006
WHERE p443.https.tls.cipher_suite = 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA';` Why it is not working with me? from their post, they claim it should work with BigQuery. Can you please explain the problem?

Comment: Well, the only difference in the table name: instead `FROM domain_public.20171006` I typed `FROM domain_public.current` which is a table that I see in the panel as shown in the screenshot in the OP.

Comment: can you provide the schema of table `domain_public.current`. At least data type of `p443.https.tls.cipher_suite` column

Comment: @enle lin thanks for your pointer. That solved part of the problem. The `p443.https.tls.cipher_suite` is RECORD and I should have used `p443.https.tls.cipher_suite.name` which is a string. After solving this issue, there is [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51395256/error-not-found-dataset-my-project-namedomain-public-was-not-found-in-locatio?noredirect=1#comment89772814_51395256) which has not been solved even after I tried all possible processing locations available to me. Can you help with that?

Comment: @user9371654 will answer in this another question if I find something interesting. In this question, I think windmark answer is proper since he pointed out the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting the error

```
Error: No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING>, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [4:7]
```

tells us that your line

```
WHERE filed3 = "some_string_here";
```

has an incorrect comparison. The left side has `STRUCT<id STRING, name STRING>` which makes it seem like filed3 is either a struct field or a table on its own. Comparing this with the string "some_string_here" is therefore not valid.